# Why does accessing a property of indexOf still compile?

Tags: typescript, methods, properties

I made a typo in TypeScript which was picked up during code review.

I used `someArray.indexOf[someObject]` instead of `someArray.indexOf(someObject)`.

I would expect an error from the IDE/Compiler. Instead, no errors were raised and the result was simply undefined.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What did you assign the result of? Because what you wrote is *valid* you are taking the `someObject` member of the `indexOf` method. Well, trying to. The only error would come from TypeScript compilation and only if you try to assign the result to something that doesn't match the expected type.

Comment: Welcome to javascript, where everything is an object!

Comment: @DeWetvanAs I am actually curious about your problem - this seems like a genuine bug/problem with TypeScript [see example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-oqp8ea). It seems that if you are trying to assign to a variable of type `number`, the result of `.indexOf[someObject]` *shouldn't* be considered a `number` and thus the compilation would fail. That's the whole idea of **Type**Script is - to enforce the types. The answers here focus on JS but ignore this.

Comment: @vlaz it was in fact a complex object with multiple properties.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Quite easy.

`someArray.indexOf` you know that this is a `function`, which is also an object and can have properties.

By doing `someArray.indexOf[someObject]`, you are trying to reach the property with the key valued to the value of `someObject`.

Of course, it is not defined on the `indexOf` function, so it returns `undefined`.

Quick example that illustrates the syntax and the fact that a function can have properties ;) :

```js
const array = [];
array.indexOf['anyValue'] = 'test';
console.log(array.indexOf.anyValue);
```

**EDIT**

Here is an attempt of an answer for the TypeScript side of the question.

As you already know, TypeScript is designed to be compatible with JavaScript. Therefore, as in JS, you can access a property of an object by the following ways:

- 'Statically': `obj.property`
- 'Dynamically': `obj['property']`

By using the 'static' way to access a property, of course, TypeScript will raise an error!

But with the dynamic way of accessing the property, there is no way TypeScript compiler can determine the type of it or if it exists or not, since the value between bracket will be evaluated at runtime, after TypeScript transpiling.

That's why it will be implicitly marked as `any`.

As David Sherret mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256211/5860648), you can force TypeScript to raise an error by adding the flag `--noImplicitAny`, please refer to his answer for more details about this!

Hoping this helps ;)

Comment: I think answers here are missing the `TypeScript` tag. It's entirely reasonable to expect a compilation error in TS. Then again, it depends if you have `index: number` and `index = arr.indexOf[obj]` then that should be a compilation error. But `index: any` wouldn't throw a compilation error.

Comment: @vlaz +1. sjahan gives OP a quick explanation of the `undefined` result but the main question remains...

Comment: "*Of course, someone could say the compiler could understand*" **Yes**, the compiler would understand. That is the entire reason for the compiler to be there and if **Type**Script can't figure out that type is undetermined, then what good is TS at all? That's just a logical examination of the statement - [David Sherret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256211/3689450) points out that TS does indeed understand undetermined types and can raise an error for it. So your edit dispenses incorrect assumptions and information.

Comment: @vlaz I think I didn't express myself correctly and my point could get misinterpreted. I'm going to edit the last part, thank you.

Answer (score 24):

It does not error because the `--noImplicitAny` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) is not enabled. With that compiler option enabled you will get an error as expected:

[image: noImplicitAny enabled]

The reason is that an element access expression returns an object typed as `any` when the type has no [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) defined (this is an implicit `any`).

[image]

So again, since `--noImplicitAny` is not enabled, it does not error. I highly recommend turning this compiler option on.

Answer (score 6):

`array.indexOf` is a function.

Functions are objects.

You were accessing the `someObject` property of the `array.indexOf` function.

You would have got `undefined`.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]
const someObject = 'asdasd'

console.log(array.indexOf[someObject])
// undefined
```

Comment: `Array.indexOf` is `undefined`, `Array.prototype.indexOf`, on the other hand, is a function.

Comment: You’re right! I fixed the typo in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only real issue here is that you expected Typescript to throw an error that exposed the problem in your logic. The intended logic was to use curly braces and utilise the `someArray.indexOf(someObject)` function.

What happened when you used square braces, `someArray.indexOf[someObject]`, was that the JS runtime first converted your object `someObject` into a string by calling the function `someObject.toString`, which most likely returned `"[object object]"`. Then the `someArray.indexOf` object was queried for the key `"[object object]"` which wasn't present, returning `undefined`. As far as Typescript goes, this is completely fine.

David Sherret pointed out that `--noImplicitAny` would have pointed out the error, but it would only have pointed out a different error, as he explained, which would not directly have helped you to find the flaw in your logic.

Comment: "*As far as Typescript goes, this is completely fine.*" no, it's not. The result of this expression would be undetermined, TypeScript would recognise it as much and should report an error because the return *type* would be `any` as opposed to `number`. Which is **not** fine for *Type*Script - remember, it's there to ensure the type safety. Saying "Oh, it's fine that you want one thing but you are have no guarantee of getting it" - that's the opposite of the core intention of TS.