# Why typescript doesn't check undefined when calling specific array index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, graphql-codegen

I'm trying to investigate why there is a runtime error when I called article.posts[0].title

I have post and posts and I want to call the first post of article (posts[0].title).
typescript assume I have posts size greater than 0 and doesn't throw any error.

```
type Post = {
    title: string
    url: string
}

type Posts = Maybe<Array<Post>>

type Article = {
   posts: Posts
}
```

and global type

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null;
```

is there a typescript rule, eslint plugin or editor plugin that can detect this issue?

```
const article: Article = {
    posts: [],
}

article.posts?.[0].url
```

the final and correct code should be

```
const article: Article = {
    posts: [],
}

article.posts?.[0]?.url
```

thank you in advance.

[image]
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmBQh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does accessing a property of indexOf still compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254396/why-does-accessing-a-property-of-indexof-still-compile)

Comment: It’s an intentional looseness in typing to allow for idiomatic code; there is a compiler option to tighten it up but it’s considered too invasive to be included in the standard `—strict` suite. See the q/a linked above the question for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the array at index with `at`:

```
const arr: string[] = [];
const x = arr.at(0).toUpperCase();
```

Here you can see a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=2&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhtBBLMBzA2gXRgF4YCBuAKFElgA9j4kA6OKACgAYBKJqEAVQAOggKYIAwnAgi2XMkA).

Mind that it won't check the index or the array length, but it will force you to check if the element exists before accessing it.

The above code does not compile:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)

While the following does compile:

```
const arr: string[] = [];
const x = arr.at(0)?.toUpperCase();
```

In other words, the type of `arr[0]` is `string`, while the type of `arr.at(0)` is `string | undefined`.

A good practice could be never accessing an array with the square brackets notation, but:

- use `.at(...)` to access specific indices of the array
- use functional methods like `.map`, `.filter`, `.reduce` and so on to iterate over the array

Answer (score 0):

In Short, To make typescript compatible with JavaScript.

1. TypeScript aims to be a useful tool for JavaScript developers and doesn't want to introduce behavior that significantly deviates from JavaScript. In JavaScript, accessing an index that is out of bounds simply returns undefined without throwing an error. TypeScript, by default, maintains this behavior.

   ```js
   const array = [];
   array.indexOf['anyValue'] = 'test';
   console.log(array.indexOf.anyValue);
   // This is valid javascript code.
   ```
2. Typescript checks types at compile time. At runtime, we are running javascript code where all types are removed. Let's say array has dynamic length. you are adding/removing elements at runtime. TypeScript cannot check out of bound error at runtime. As typescript only checks at compile time.

To add out of bound check, this is one possible solution:
Use if condition.

```
if(article.posts.length>0){
article.posts[0].url; // access now
}
```

Code example credit goes to [sjahan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254438/12429704)

Comment: don't just copy answers from a question that I added as a duplicate.